# paytm integration in core php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to integrate paytm wallet in my site . what is parameter can be used and what parameter can be used to generate checksum ?

```
$data=array();
    $data["MID"]=$this->merchant_id;
    $data["ORDER_ID"]=$param['transaction_id'];
    $data["CUST_ID"]=$user['id'];
    $data["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"]=$this->industry_type;
    if($param['paytm_type']=="WEB"){
        $data["CHANNEL_ID"]=$this->web_channel_id;
        $data["WEBSITE"]=$this->web_website;
    }
    else if($param['paytm_type']=="APP"){
        $data["CHANNEL_ID"]=$this->app_channel_id;
        $data["WEBSITE"]=$this->app_name;
    }
    $data["TXN_AMOUNT"]=$param['amount'];
```

and my postfiled data like

```
$postfiled=array(        
        "MID"         =>$data["MID"],
        "ORDER_ID"    =>$param['transaction_id'],
        "CUST_ID"     =>$user['id'],
        "TXN_AMOUNT"  =>$param['amount'],
        "CHANNEL_ID"  =>$data["CHANNEL_ID"],
        "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"=>$data["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"],
        "WEBSITE"     =>$data["WEBSITE"],
        "CHECKSUMHASH"=>  \App\Lib\PaytmLib\encdec_paytm::getChecksumFromArray($data,$this->merchant_key),
        "END_POINT"   =>$this->end_point,
        "CALLBACK_URL"=>$returnUrl
    );
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ? better to check here : http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_api_doc?target=integration-guide

Comment: i m use CHANNEL_ID="WAP"  and WEBSITE="APP_STAGING"

Comment: then i m redirect to payment page but not gatting pay now button ? can explain me how can i do , so i m looking pay now button

Answer (score 0):

You can use below functions for paytm checksum. [Here](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_PHP) is the sample kit for PHP.

```
 1. getChecksumFromString : For generating the checksum
 2. verifychecksum_eFromStr : For verifing the checksum
```

Comment: i m use CHANNEL_ID="WAP" and WEBSITE="APP_STAGING"  . then i m redirect to payment page but not gatting pay now button ? can explain me how can i do , so i m looking pay now button